# jQuery plugin not looping through matched items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I've got a really simple plugin I am trying to make. All it does is get the matched item, and prepend a div to it of the same height that animates to the width specified by the user in a data-attribute in their HTML.

When I run it on my test page which is just a few divs, only the last div is affected by the plugin, none of the others.

Here is my sad attempt at a plugin:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.skillBarLoad = function( colourGiven, speedGiven) {

     var appendedSkillBar = $("<div></div>");
     appendedSkillBar.css({
         "border-radius": "inherit",
         "height": "100%",
         "width": "0%",
         "background-color": colourGiven
     });

    return this.each( function() {

    $(this).prepend(appendedSkillBar);
    var percentageFromData = $(this).attr('data-load-percent');

    appendedSkillBar.animate( {
        width: percentageFromData + "%"
     }, speedGiven);
    });
}

}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".skillBar").skillBarLoad("blue", 2000);
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="skillBar" data-load-percent="90"></div>
    <div class="skillBar" data-load-percent="90"></div>
    <div class="skillBar" data-load-percent="90"></div>
</body>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="jquery.skill-bars.js"></script>
</html>
```

Obviously any help or advice or a gentle hint at the problem I'm not seeing is very appreciated.

Have a nice day everyone.

EDIT: ANSWER PROVIDED IN COMMENTS

.prepend() will not copy the element multiple times so instead .clone() was used before hand and then this clone was prepended instead.

Comment: I have a feeling that `this` in your selects only the last element.

Comment: @callback Do you know if the "this" causing the problem would be the first this, or the second one wrapped in $(); Sorry, if that seems beginner-ish. That's exactly what I am!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/: _“If a single element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)”_ – your `appendedSkillBar` is such a single element in that regard. Therefor, it gets moved from one div to the next in each of your `each` iterations, ending up being only in the last one after the loop is finished.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot. I'll definitely make a note of that. Is there a function similar to prepend that does allow multiple copies. I can't find any on jQuery's dom insertion page. Thanks again.

Comment: Well you could simply clone the element yourself, and then prepend that clone.

Comment: @CBroe That is exactly what I did just before I read your comment. Thanks a lot. I will update my post with the solution. I know for you guys it is probably obvious but it's just incase someone like me has the same problem. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one `$(<div></div>)` per iteration of the `.each()`.

You can also do things more efficiently by defining the CSS map once, before the loop.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.skillBarLoad = function(colourGiven, speedGiven) {
        var cssMap = {
            "border-radius": "inherit",
            "height": "100%",
            "width": "0%",
            "background-color": colourGiven
        };
        return this.each( function() {
            $("<div/>").css(cssMap).animate({
                width: $(this).data('load-percent') + "%"
            }, speedGiven).prependTo(this);
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```